# How to pattern match a complex file path

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java 8. I have a scenario where user can upload a document and I have to compare if the  uploaded path contains the below path format:

```
"/abc:doc_home{anyWord}/xyz:docFolder{anyWord}/[someWord]/def:library{anyWord}"
```

I need the curly braces where I have indicated above and within that any word can be included. Is it possible to do this in regex?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score -2):

You have included `anyWord` twice in the expression. If you intended for these two words to be *the same* word, then no, that is not possible to do with regular expressions.

Comment: Those words could be anything and not needed to be same

Comment: In that case, it is possible.

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible? Are you aware of backreferences?

Comment: This is a comment at best, and not a very good one at that. I suggest getting familiar with https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Comment: Backreferences are not part of regular expressions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages

Comment: You are forgiven. You can follow the link for more info.

Comment: Regular expressions have evolved far beyond the purist definition which you seem to be hung up on. Can you explain why you would choose to confuse OP given that they clearly want to achieve something in the Java flavor of regex?

Comment: How is he confused? He's not even trying to use non-regular grammar.